# Deleted a file, now can't create a file of the same name

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I created a file with the following Node.js code:

```js
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage')
var gcs = new Storage()
var bucket = gcs.bucket('bucket-name')

const file = bucket.file('filename')

// fileData is a utf8 buffer
file.save(fileData, function(err) {
  console.log('Error:' + err)
})
```

Then, I went in through the Cloud Console and deleted the file.

I then ran the code above again, but received the error "[service account] does not have storage.objects.delete access to bucket-name/filename."  So I went in and added storage.objects.delete access to the service account through IAM, but I continue to get the error.

It seems that the object is still sitting inside the bucket, and it still has the old service account access (without storage.objects.delete), but I don't see the object anywhere.  Versioning is suspended on this bucket.

I have since gone through the same steps with the same bucket but using a different filename and don't see the error message.  This seems to show that the new service account access is being properly applied to new files, but not to old files.  This is surprising, since I'm using "Bucket Policy Only" on this bucket.

Can anyone figure out how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have reproduced your code and it works perfectly for me, to further troubleshoot your issue you can open an issue [1] with your project's details so we can look into it. PS: you can mention that you came from here and that i offered to looking into this.
[1] https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491168

Comment: Are you able to write to other filenames in the bucket? Is it possible the service account just doesn't have write permissions on the bucket?

Comment: @David Yes, I am able to write to other filenames. After adding storage.objects.delete to the account's permissions, I'm able to write, delete, then write again to new files. The only difference seems to be that the original file was created when the account didn't have storage.objects.delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cloud Storage Object metadata 

        1. await bucket
                    .file(filePath)
                    .delete({ ignoreNotFound: true });
    
        // Deleting file with a name.
        
        const blob = bucket.file(filePath);
        
       2. await blob.save(fil?.buffer);
    
        //Saving File with the same name 
        
       3. const [metadata] = await storage
                  .bucket(bucketName)
                  .file(filePath)
                  .getMetadata();
        
        newDocObj.location = metadata.mediaLink;
    
    I have used metadata.mediaLink to get the latest download link 
    of the uploaded file from Google Bucket Storage.
```